# Subject-verb agreement

Tags: grammatical-number

I have read the following in German news at https://learngerman.dw.com/de/20012024-langsam-gesprochene-nachrichten/a-68040812:

> Er begrüßte die Kundgebungen, die dazu in vielen deutschen Städten
> stattfinden. Anlass sind Informationen über ein Geheimtreffen von
> Rechtsextremisten mit Politikern der Oppositionspartei AfD.

Isn't "Anlass" the subject of the 2nd sentence and therefore shouldn't the verb "sein" agree with it in the singular? In English the verb must agree with the subject and I thought that rule also existed in German.

Maybe "Informationen über... AfD" is the subject and the word sentence is complement - verb - subject here?

It's also odd that no article is used with "Anlass". Would the same work with a synonym of "Anlass", such as "Grund"?

Comment: The subject in the sentence is "Informationen". This sentence is about what the occasion is, and that is precisely the "information". The verb "sind" combines the subject "information" with the predicate "occasion" to express that the information is the reason or occasion for something.
The article can be omitted because a kind of equation takes place here, in which "Anlass" functions as a predicate noun after the verb "sein". In such constructions, it is not uncommon in German to omit the article, especially when dealing with abstract concepts or states.

Comment: This omission of the article serves to draw attention to the nature or quality of the subject, in this case the general condition or role as "Anlass", without referring to a specific, single occasion. It is a stylistic choice that makes the statement more general and less specific, which is often used in news, headlines or similar contexts to convey a broader or more abstract meaning.

Comment: "Grund" and "Anlass" are usually used as Synonyms, but there is a little difference.  
"Grund" provides the deeper explanation for an event and is often more abstract and comprehensive, while "Anlass" represents the concrete trigger or specific moment that leads to an action or event. In practice, the boundaries between the two concepts can become blurred and in many contexts they are used interchangeably, although these subtle differences exist.

Comment: Imho the "This question already has answers" tag is wrong.